# Am unable to create multiple 'DATE' attributes in mysql tables

Tags: mysql, database

```
mysql> create table Members(
    -> M_id int not null,
    -> B_id int not null,
    -> M_name varchar(20),
    -> M_address varchar(20),
    -> Issue DATE,
    -> Return DATE,
    -> Expiry_date DATE,
    -> primary key(M_id),
    -> foreign key(B_id) references books(B_id));
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Return DATE,
>   Expiry_date DATE,
>   primary key(M_id),
>   foreign key(B_id) references b' at line 7

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are using reserved words as column names. Quote all column names and table names with backticks `.

Comment: A good tip is to avoid using reserved words as table/column identifiers. It's not easy to remember the entire list of reserved words (and it keeps growing, slowly), but when you get an error message like this, it quickly gets pretty easy to guess why.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to quote all entities (ie. tables, columns, etc.) using backticks (<kbd>`</kbd>) so 
that if one of them happens to be a reserved word in MySQL, it can tell the difference.

The backtick is usually in the top left corner of the keyboard.

```
create table `Members`
(
    `M_id` int not null,
    `B_id` int not null,
    `M_name` varchar(20),
    `M_address` varchar(20),
    `Issue` DATE,
    `Return` DATE,
    `Expiry_date` DATE,
primary key(`M_id`),
foreign key(`B_id`) references books(B_id)
);
```

Comment: The tilde (`~`) and backtick are separate keys

Comment: @Martin - Not on my keyboard. Also note the "usually". Are you using a MAC?

Comment: The key for these characters varies in the keyboard layout in many countries. https://sites.google.com/site/brightmeasurement/Home/keyboard-for-english-around-the-word

Comment: The backtick is ***NOT*** usually the same key as the tilde symbol. This is specific only to Sloan Thrasher's keyboard and should not be taken as any form of standard. It is detrimental to state otherwise as this will confuse people who are not familiar with either of these symbols.

Comment: @Martin it's there for keyboards in India, China, and the US, so I would be comfortable with the use of the word "usually" here.

Comment: @Rogue that still does not make it a standard.

Comment: Nope, but it certainly allows for the use of the word "usually". Anyhow this is somewhat pedantic, I would hope to assume that anyone on a programming Q&A site can find the backtick key on their keyboard

Comment: Keyboards are **NOT** standard, to any country or region. There are many layouts of keyboard (really dependings on the quality of the manufacturer; where they source their parts from); so there is wide scope for needless confusion.

Comment: `I would hope to assume that anyone on a programming Q&A site can find the tilde key on their keyboard` I absolutely agree, but spending time on the internet and SO leads me to believe that you should never underestimate how *un-smart* some humans can be! `;-)`

Comment: Basic programming paradigm: Seperation of Concerns. Where the tilde key may be located is completely irrelevant to where the backtick key may be located.  `:-)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Am actually starting to learn Mysql. This is helpful

Comment: @MithunJayabalan, if this answer solved, or helped solve your question, please mark as accepted.